# What html tag & syntax for inserting a text box in the middle of a text?

Tags: html, css

HTML question. I want to insert a text box/block in an HTML page full of plain text. I want this text box to be aligned to the right and to be surrounded by the plain text (wrap). I also want to define the dimensions of the text box (width as % of the window, etc.) My goal is to insert a Latin text box into the Greek plain text in **this example:** http://kobzar.be/tmp/delme-020.pdf .
I suppose this must be sort of `div` or `span` or `inline-block` tag, but I'm not sure. Please advise.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65522530/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `float` css propery.

```
.text-inside {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

<div>
  TEXT OUTSIDE
  <div class="text-inside">
    TEXT INSIDE
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH @Kromel! I did as you said, it worked! Look: http://kobzar.be/html.html#loremipsum

Comment: @Frager Do not forget to [**clear**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) after any float ;)